# Adding DISTINCT to a UNION query

Tags: mysql, sql, union, distinct, union-all

How do I get distinct title.id's from this:

```
 SELECT Title.id, Title.title FROM titles as Title HAVING points > 0 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT Title.id, Title.title FROM titles as Title HAVING points > 1
```

There is more to the query but this should be enough to go on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just remove the `ALL`. Some flavors allow adding `DISTINCT` instead of `ALL` to be more explicit, but that's redundant having that the default is always to filter our duplicates.

MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html
MSSQL - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx
ORACLE - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm
PostgreSQL - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/queries-union.html
etc.

Comment: "The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements."

Comment: I couldn't find the official reference for Oracle, so if anyone knows it please edit the answer or post it in a comment and I'll change it.

Comment: @tofutim A quote would be good in the answer, but that is from the MySQL manual and he said nothing about using MySQL.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, forgot to add that, but there is more to the query.  See my edits above.  The points column throws the uniqueness off.

Comment: i still get duplicate id's though.  Not sure how to get rid of those.

Comment: oh well, i might have an idea

Comment: @chris I feared that would be a problem. Wrap it in a `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY Title.id`. Although I'm not sure about the performance of this kind of solution.

Comment: Ya i might have to eat the performance on that, thx for your help.

Comment: @chris: if you get duplicate ids, you may be doing something wrong in the inner queries (possibly with JOINs). Post those queries too.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the simple way just get rid of the union and the second part altogether:

```
SELECT Title.id, Title.title FROM titles as Title HAVING points > 0
```

since `HAVING points > 0` includes anything with `HAVING points > 1`?

Comment: That was just a simplistic example.

Answer (score 1):

You could drop the `ALL` as others have suggested.

If the two queries use same tables and are different only in the `WHERE` clause or only in the `HAVING` clause, you can also use this:

```
SELECT Title.id, Title.title FROM titles as Title
WHERE (1st query conditions)
   OR (2nd query conditions)
```

or

```
SELECT Title.id, Title.title FROM titles as Title
HAVING (1st query conditions)
    OR (2nd query conditions)
```